# Url rule overrides in Yii

Tags: yii2, url-routing

I am just getting into Yii and so do excuse me if this looks blindingly obvious. I am trying to setup some URL rules so that:

www.example.com/my_page & www.example.com/my_page/my_subpage

both hit the main pages controller and the content pulled from a database, then:

www.example.com/admin/pages/edit

Works from the Admin Controller. I seem to have an either or situation at present, can anyone shed some light as to where I may be going wrong?

This is what I currently have in my web config file:

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            //'<key>' => 'pages/index',
            'admin/<action:\w+>' => 'admin/index',
        ],
    ],
```

If I toggle the commenting on either line 5 or 6 then it seems to work as I expect, however having both lines uncommented the '' line takes precedent.

Comment: Do want have like this: www.domain.com/"member"/index

Comment: See the doc : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#using-pretty-urls

Comment: @farshid The first set of pages refer to pages contained in the database as they are all from root level of the domain. However the second part of this is that if there is a physical controller that matches the first part of the route ie www.domain.com/admin where admin is a physically existing controller then it uses that rather than querying the database for a page called 'admin'

Comment: Have your tried switching your rules order? I mean, putting first the one for the admin part.